# Unable to save data from datagridview

Tags: vb.net

what is happening is i would like to save the data quantity in column qty it works on a single row however once you place multiple row entry it gives the error with in the comm starts here:

Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection while saving multiple gridview data

```vb
.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pid", CInt(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value.ToString))
```

```
Private Sub BtnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnSave.Click
    TxtReferenceNo.Text.Trim()
    TxtReceiveBy.Text.Trim()

    For a As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        If DataGridView1.Rows(a).Cells(7).Value = String.Empty Then
            MsgBox("Quantity must not be empty", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "")
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next

    Dim sdate As String = DateTimeReceived.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
    Dim d1, d2 As Date
    Dim found As Boolean
    d1 = sdate
    d2 = Now.ToShortDateString

    If d1 <> d2 Then
        MsgBox("Date should should be current date", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim Tsql As String
        Tsql = "select * from tblstockin where refno like '" & TxtReferenceNo.Text & "'"
        '"' and pid like '" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value.ToString &
        '"' and sdate like '" & sdate & "'"

        Con = New MySqlConnection
        With Con
            If .State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                .ConnectionString = StrCon
                .Open()
            End If
        End With

        Comm = New MySqlCommand(Tsql, Con)
        dr = Comm.ExecuteReader
        dr.Read()
        If dr.HasRows Then
            found = True
        End If
        dr.Close()
        Con.Close()

        Try
            If Not (IsNumeric(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(7).Value.ToString)) Then
                MsgBox("Quantity should be numeric", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "")
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try


        If found = False Then
            Dim sql As String

            sql = "insert into tblstockin (refno, receivedby, pid, qty, sdate) 
                  values (@refno, @receivedby, @pid, @qty, @sdate) "

            'sql = "insert into tblstockin (refno, receivedby, pid, qty, sdate) " &
            '"values ('" & TxtReferenceNo.Text & "',
            '         '" & TxtReceiveBy.Text & "', 
            '         '" & CInt(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value.ToString) & "',
            '         '" & CInt(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(7).Value.ToString) & "', 
            '         '" & sdate & "') "

            Con = New MySqlConnection
            With Con
                If .State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                    .ConnectionString = StrCon
                    .Open()
                End If
            End With

            Comm = New MySqlCommand(sql, Con)
            With Comm
                .Parameters.Clear()
                .CommandText = sql
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@refno", TxtReferenceNo.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@receivedby", TxtReceiveBy.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@pid", CInt(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value.ToString))
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", CInt(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(7).Value.ToString))
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@sdate", sdate)
            End With

            If MessageBox.Show("Are you sure to save Stock", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) = DialogResult.Yes Then
                Dim result As Integer = Comm.ExecuteNonQuery
                MsgBox("Stock has been saved", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "")
                TxtReceiveBy.Clear()
                TxtCount.Clear()
                Con.Close()

                Dim hsql As String
                hsql = " insert into tblgenid (codeid, code) values (@codeid, @code) "

                Con = New MySqlConnection
                With Con
                    If .State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                        .ConnectionString = StrCon
                        .Open()
                    End If
                End With

                Comm = New MySqlCommand(hsql, Con)
                With Comm
                    .Parameters.Clear()
                    .CommandText = hsql
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@codeid", LblD.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@code", TxtReferenceNo.Text)
                End With
                Comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Con.Close()
                TxtReferenceNo.Clear()
            End If

            'Dim fsql As String
            'fsql = "update tblproduct set qty=@qty where id=@id"

            Dim rsql As String
            rsql = "update tblproduct set qty = qty + " & CInt(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(7).Value.ToString) &
                " where id like '" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value.ToString & "'"
            'alternate code to update product quantity in product table
            'will update or add the number indicated on quantity to the existing product number in table

            Con = New MySqlConnection
            With Con
                If .State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                    .ConnectionString = StrCon
                    .Open()
                End If
            End With

            Comm = New MySqlCommand(rsql, Con)
            With Comm
                .Parameters.Clear()
                .CommandText = rsql
                '.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", CInt(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(7).Value.ToString))
                '.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", CInt(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value.ToString))
            End With
            Comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
            DataGridView2.Rows.Clear()
            DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
            CbxSearch.ResetText()
            TxtSearch.Clear()
            TxtReferenceNo.Clear()
            Con.Close()
        Else
            MsgBox("Reference no already exists", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "")
        End If
    Next

    GenerateStock()

    With Frm_Product_List
        .LoadProductList()
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `DataGridView1.Rows(i)` will not exist after `DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()`.

Comment: Duplicate of [What is an IndexOutOfRangeException / ArgumentOutOfRangeException and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940979/what-is-an-indexoutofrangeexception-argumentoutofrangeexception-and-how-do-i-f) (scroll down to the bottom of the accepted answer for the VB.NET-related section).

Comment: Look at the name: INDEX out of RANGE exception. What did you discover when you looked to find out what the index was and what the valid range was? You may be new to programming but you still know what words mean so you can use that knowledge to do some diagnosis of your own.